# Convert number to binary string with full padding?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I have a long variable in java and am converting it to a binary string, like

long var = 24;
Long.toBinaryString(val);

Now this prints only 7 bits, but I need to display all the 64 bits, i.e. all the leading zeros also, how can I achieve this?

The reason is I need to iterate through each bit and perform an operation according to the status, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the bits, you **might be better off testing each bit** without converting it to a string:

```
if ((val & (1L << bitPosition)) != 0)
    // etc
```

But, **if you truly want a binary string**, this is the easiest way to left-pad it with zeros:

```
string padding = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
string result = padding + Long.toBinaryString(val);
result = result.substring(result.length() - 64, result.length());  // take the right-most 64 digits
```

Comment: sure there are loops... just hidden by the strcat / strcpys.  If you provided the leading '0's yourself, it would be about the same amount of work.  However, this method is nice for its simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

You can use binary operators to access the individual bits of an long. The following code prints the individual bits of "i" as "true" or "false".

```
long i = 1024;
for(int n = 63; n >= 0; n--)
    System.out.println(n + ": " + ((i & (1L << n)) != 0));
```

Comment: Cool hack to go through the loop backwards :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think it should go like this:

```
int i=0, thisbit;
mask = 1;
while (i++ < 64)
{
    thisbit = var & mask;
    // check thisbit here...
    //
    var = var >>> 1;
    mask*=2;
}
```

Comment: Well, as OP writes, the reason is to iterate through each bit and perform an operation according to the status, so there is no output, but operations on each bit in "// check thisbit here" section.

Answer (score 1):

I would add little modification on @Robert's answer. Instead of declaring padding variable here, use Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(long).

Actually internally it make use of shift operators only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html for information on bitwise operations.

Otherwise use the Formatter: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

This will work;

```
String s =  Long.toBinaryString(val);
while (s.length() < 64)
{
    s = "0" + s;
}
```

If you want to do this with a StringBuffer, so;

```
StringBuffer s =  new StringBuffer(Long.toBinaryString(val));
while (s.length() < 64)
{
    s.insert(0, "0");
}
String str = s.toString();
```